# How to show Dictionary array First Value in UITableview First Section and Remaining Value in UITableview Second Section?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

i am newbie in iOS development i Use JSON Data Array to show tableview cell data i make different Cell for Different Section it is working but now i want in my First Section Cell only Data Array first Value and In Second Section all remaining value are Show How it is possible?

I write a code for my First Cell But it was not working

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifierOne=@"CellOne";
    CustumCell *cellOne =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierOne];
    if (cellOne == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nibOne=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustumCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cellOne=[nibOne objectAtIndex:0];
        cellOne.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    }
    {
        [cellOne.spinner startAnimating];
        NSDictionary *dict = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSString *img2=[dict valueForKey:@"front_image"];
        [cellOne.storeImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[img2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Setting.png"] options:SDWebImageHighPriority completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
         {
             [cellOne.spinner stopAnimating];
             cellOne.spinner.hidesWhenStopped=YES;

         }];

    }
    return cellOne;
}
}
```

it shows error in line

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

here imagearray is a JSON parsing array.i know that it is ask many times but i not get Solution please give me Solution if it is possible.

Comment: try indexPath.row in the place of ndexPath.section

Comment: what the error shows??

Comment: not any error but application not run @SaurabhPrajapati

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i also try it but here i write numberof Rows in Section that if section is 0 means first then row =1 and section is Second then no. of rows= array.count-1;

Comment: are You sure [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] is returning NSDictionary??

Comment: Yes Bro when i try no. of rows in section in FirstSection array.count then it shows all data array. so it is returning right bro?

Comment: @AshishGabani Your First Cell Contain How Many Row?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper it is Contain Only One Row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ashish Gabani` Here Your First Section Contain Only One Row than Defie two Array Like as

```
NSArray *firstArray=[[NSArray alloc]init];
NSArray *secondArrayarray=[[NSArray alloc]init];
```

And then Write like as

```
self.firstArray=[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:0];
self.secondArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.imageArray];
[self.secondArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

And For `First Section` Load First Array Data and For `Second Section` Load Second Array Data

Hope it Help You.